# Multiple Application android:name in Android Manifest

Tags: android

I have merged two different projects file in Android Studio
My problem is both the project files needs to declare application android:name

**Android Manifest**

```
<application
    android:name=".app.AppController"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.WebViewApp.Red"
     >
```

I need to add another one right below

```
<application
    android:name=".WebViewAppApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.WebViewApp.Red"
     >
```

I know its not possible. is there any way around

**Mainactivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity
```

**WebViewAppApplication**

```
public class WebViewAppApplication extends Application
```

**AppController**

```
public class AppController extends Application
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have `WebViewAppApplication` extend `AppController`.

Or, have `AppController` extend `WebViewAppApplication`.

Or, merge the two classes together into a single class.

Or, remove the functionality from one `Application` subclass, replacing it with something else (e.g., standard Java singletons).